# Why is my for loop being ignored inside of this function?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I'm back with the rock paper scissor challenge this time!

I'm almost done with my JS file, but one of the last things is being able to stop the game. My `playGame` function is ignoring my `for` loop.

Edit: Also just realized `setTie` gets ignored as well.

```js
    (function rockPaperOrScissors() {
      let computerScore = 0;
      let playerScore = 0;
      let tie = 0;
      const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
      const paper = document.getElementById("paper");
      const scissor = document.getElementById("scissor");
    
      rock.addEventListener("click", rockChoice);
      paper.addEventListener("click", paperChoice);
      scissor.addEventListener("click", scissorChoice);
    
      function rockChoice() {
        return playGame("rock", computerPlay());
      }
      function paperChoice() {
        return playGame("paper", computerPlay());
      }
      function scissorChoice() {
        return playGame("scissor", computerPlay());
      }
    
      function computerPlay() {
        let options = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
        return options[random];
      }
    
      function compWon() {
        const sayComp = document.getElementById("announce");
        computerScore += 1;
        sayComp.innerText = `Computer wins!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function playerWon() {
        const sayPlayer = document.getElementById("announce");
        playerScore += 1;
        sayPlayer.innerText = `You win!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function setTie() {
        const sayTie = document.getElementById("announce");
        tie += 1;
        sayTie.innerText = `It's a tie.\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function gameOver() {
        const endGame = document.getElementById("announce");
        endGame.innerText += `Game Over!\n Computer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        rock.removeEventListener("click", rockChoice);
        paper.removeEventListener("click", paperChoice);
        scissor.removeEventListener("click", scissorChoice);
        return;
      }
    
      function playGame(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
          if (playerSelection === "scissor") {
            if (computerSelection === "rock") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
    
          if (playerSelection === "paper") {
            if (computerSelection === "scissor") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
    
          if (playerSelection === "rock") {
            if (computerSelection === "paper") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
          if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
            --i;
            return setTie();
          }
        }
        gameOver();
      }
      playGame();
    })();
```

```html
    

      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <header>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissor</h1>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div class="names">
          <h2>Player Score:</h2>
          <h2>Computer Score:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
          <h3 id="userScore"></h3>
          <h3 id="compScore"></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p id="announce"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button id="rock">Rock</button>
          <button id="paper">Paper</button>
          <button id="scissor">Scissor</button>
        </div>
      </body>
      <footer>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </footer>
    </html>
```

As always, if you could also show me ways to shorten/make the code better please do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented out code that was not doing anything.
Your current logic never uses the loop, as it will return from the function after the result of each game.  It also never reaches the gameOver call.  Using a for loop is not the proper way to end the game after 3 rounds.

You need to have a counter for how many games are played.  I've added a counter "games" and have it return from the function and execute gameOver() when it reaches 3 games.

Your gameOver function needs to be fixed, as just appending that text there is probably not what you want.

```js
(function rockPaperOrScissors() {
      let computerScore = 0;
      let playerScore = 0;
      let tie = 0;
      const rock = document.getElementById("rock");
      const paper = document.getElementById("paper");
      const scissor = document.getElementById("scissor");
    
      rock.addEventListener("click", rockChoice);
      paper.addEventListener("click", paperChoice);
      scissor.addEventListener("click", scissorChoice);
    
      function rockChoice() {
        return playGame("rock", computerPlay());
      }
      function paperChoice() {
        return playGame("paper", computerPlay());
      }
      function scissorChoice() {
        return playGame("scissor", computerPlay());
      }
    
      function computerPlay() {
        let options = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
        return options[random];
      }
    
      function compWon() {
        const sayComp = document.getElementById("announce");
        computerScore += 1;
        sayComp.innerText = `Computer wins!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function playerWon() {
        const sayPlayer = document.getElementById("announce");
        playerScore += 1;
        sayPlayer.innerText = `You win!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function setTie() {
        const sayTie = document.getElementById("announce");
        tie += 1;
        sayTie.innerText = `It's a tie.\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        return;
      }
    
      function gameOver() {
        const endGame = document.getElementById("announce");
        endGame.innerText += `Game Over!\n Computer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore} Tie: ${tie}`;
        rock.removeEventListener("click", rockChoice);
        paper.removeEventListener("click", paperChoice);
        scissor.removeEventListener("click", scissorChoice);
        return;
      }
    
    let games = 0;
      function playGame(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
//        for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
          if (++games === 3) return gameOver();
          if (playerSelection === "scissor") {
            if (computerSelection === "rock") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
    
          if (playerSelection === "paper") {
            if (computerSelection === "scissor") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
    
          if (playerSelection === "rock") {
            if (computerSelection === "paper") {
              return compWon();
            } else {
              return playerWon();
            }
          }
          if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
//            --i;
            return setTie();
          }
//        }
//        gameOver();
      }
//      playGame();
    })();
```

```html
HTML:

      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <header>
        <h1>Rock Paper Scissor</h1>
      </header>
      <body>
        <div class="names">
          <h2>Player Score:</h2>
          <h2>Computer Score:</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
          <h3 id="userScore"></h3>
          <h3 id="compScore"></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p id="announce"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button id="rock">Rock</button>
          <button id="paper">Paper</button>
          <button id="scissor">Scissor</button>
        </div>
      </body>
      <footer>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </footer>
    </html>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I know it's not fully complete but I wanted to get this working before I moved on. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure.  Be careful of the trap of expecting loops to "wait" for a value to change before continuing.  That's not how the execution flow works.  Seems like a common programming mistake (I've seen 5 of them just today on here).  That type of functionality only occurs when you use Promise and await syntax or events that inform you of an action that has changed the value.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why the ```setTie``` doesn't seem to run as well? It runs if I put it towards the top though. Is there a way I can add ```--games``` so that it doesn't end the game without a clear winner?

Comment: You mean don't end the game unless playerWins != computerWins?  So you would change it to be games >= 3 && playerScore!==computerScore

Comment: I tried adding ```&&& playerScore !== computerScore``` it seems like it goes back to unlimited games.

Comment: Your if statements for checking wins will always return before it reaches setTies, because you use "else" in your statements, which means that it returns a tie as a loss before it can reach the setTie statement.  You need to move the setTie logic to the top so ties are checked first.  returns break out of the function immediately with the value

Comment: You need to use greater than, because games++ will continue to increment.  Do you know how to use the debugger?  You can set a breakpoint in the chrome developer console in "sources" tab.  That way you can see what is happening during execution

Comment: I'm going to focus on the debugger tomorrow since it seems like it'll solve most of my issues. Would you recommend I change the if statements to something else so I don't run into these issues? Thanks for answering so many questions!

Comment: Moving your setTie if block to the top of the function before you check for wins would be enough to fix it.  The code might be easier to read if you refactored it, but it's not really necessary.  You could have gotten rid of all the else statements, and just used a fall-through return computerWon() at the bottom, and combined the 3 win conditions into just one check.

Comment: Once you get the code working, you might want to go over to codereview.stackexchange.com to get help on improving the code style.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody is going to come along and tell you that your program isn't even close to a minimum test case.

That said, I'm confident your loop isn't being ignored.  Instead, one of two things is happening:
1) the function is never run at all
2) the loop is never reaching a condition which causes it to do anything useful.

The easiest way to troubleshoot this is either to use `console.log()` messages inside the function and loop, or use your debugger.

I would recommend learning how to use the debugger, it will serve you well and the time spent learning it will pay for itself almost immediately.

To start, just stick a `debugger;` statement at the top of your for loop, and enable the debugger in your browser's developer console.  You will be to step through the code, examine variables, one line at a time.